# how to select a list from random id to the last

Tags: mysql, sql

im new with SQL. i know to how select a list with limit comand. but that way need a value to select. what if i want select a list from random id to the last.  exemple:

I want to select a list with id from 4 -> last of row (cuz i dont know whats last id)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using SQL Server, MySQL , Oracle etc..... also what have you tried so far ????

Comment: im using mysql. this is my first time im working with database

Comment: How do you get the random id ? From user input or a random number generator?

Comment: i mean "the id that i already know" to "the last id what i dont know" (sr my bad eng)

Comment: You can execute a query to get the last id like this: `select id from table order by id desc limit 1`. This will give you the last id. Use this in next query like this: `select * from table limit 4, [id form previous query]`. Which server side language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from thing1 where id>=4 order by rand();
```

where `thing1` is your table name. How you seed your random number generator (RNG) is up to you.

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | conn_id | read_date  |
+----+---------+------------+
| 11 |       3 | 2013-02-21 |
|  5 |       1 | 2012-02-21 |
|  8 |       5 | 2010-12-21 |
| 15 |       7 | 2019-12-21 |
| 14 |       6 | 2019-12-21 |
| 13 |       5 | 2016-02-21 |
|  4 |       2 | 2010-12-21 |
|  7 |       2 | 2014-02-21 |
|  6 |       2 | 2007-12-21 |
| 12 |       4 | 2014-02-21 |
| 16 |       8 | 2010-12-21 |
|  9 |       3 | 2010-12-21 |
| 10 |       4 | 2010-12-21 |
+----+---------+------------+
13 rows in set (0.14 sec)

mysql> select * from thing1 where id>=4 order by rand();
+----+---------+------------+
| id | conn_id | read_date  |
+----+---------+------------+
| 13 |       5 | 2016-02-21 |
|  6 |       2 | 2007-12-21 |
| 10 |       4 | 2010-12-21 |
| 16 |       8 | 2010-12-21 |
| 14 |       6 | 2019-12-21 |
|  5 |       1 | 2012-02-21 |
|  7 |       2 | 2014-02-21 |
| 11 |       3 | 2013-02-21 |
| 12 |       4 | 2014-02-21 |
|  4 |       2 | 2010-12-21 |
|  8 |       5 | 2010-12-21 |
|  9 |       3 | 2010-12-21 |
| 15 |       7 | 2019-12-21 |
+----+---------+------------+
13 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from thing1 where id>=4 order by rand();
+----+---------+------------+
| id | conn_id | read_date  |
+----+---------+------------+
| 10 |       4 | 2010-12-21 |
|  4 |       2 | 2010-12-21 |
|  6 |       2 | 2007-12-21 |
|  7 |       2 | 2014-02-21 |
|  5 |       1 | 2012-02-21 |
|  9 |       3 | 2010-12-21 |
| 12 |       4 | 2014-02-21 |
| 16 |       8 | 2010-12-21 |
|  8 |       5 | 2010-12-21 |
| 15 |       7 | 2019-12-21 |
| 13 |       5 | 2016-02-21 |
| 14 |       6 | 2019-12-21 |
| 11 |       3 | 2013-02-21 |
+----+---------+------------+
13 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

### Stored Proc

To have starting random position, until the end, random ordering

```
-- drop procedure getRandomStartToEnd;
delimiter $$
create procedure getRandomStartToEnd()
BEGIN
    declare theCount int;
    declare theStart int;

    select count(*) into theCount from thing1;
    set @theStart:=floor((rand()*@theCount)+1);
    select * from thing1 where id>=@theStart order by rand();
END
$$

call getRandomStartToEnd;   -- call stored proc
```

Comment: If, we don't use `rand()` we will still get the required results and that too in an ordered manner.

Comment: ty  captain i got it :D